# extract schema for sql server compact edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to generate the sql statement for tables in sql server compact ?
same as for sql server express+ ?

Essentially a create table( .... ) statement as output ?

Answer (score 5):

There is a project on [Codeplex](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/) that someone has actually built the functionality to be able to do scripting for sql server compact edition databases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool to do this. Check out http://www.antipodeansoftware.com/Home/Products
This will iterate the entire SQL server, and write all the table, view, stored procedure and UDF scripts to a local drive. Great for adding SQL schema or DDL to source control.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [SQLite & SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox) has versions for Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio. I've used the latter version successfully to add columns and export the schema as CREATE TABLE statements from SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to SQL Server Compact Edition using SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS), which in turn allows you to script out all database objects.

Please refer to: [Managing SQL Server Compact Edition with SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172933(SQL.90).aspx)

and then also, [How to: Generate a Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx)

Comment: Script generation (and many other features) are hidden/disabled when you open a .sdf file (SQL Server CE) in SSMS.