# How can I extract sprocs/tables/functions from a specific schema?

Tags: sql-server-2008, extract, database-schema

I need to extract all the tables, stored procs and functions from an SQL Server 08 db that are under a particular schema. I *could* filter the displayed items in Management Studio and then do `Script As -> Drop/Create` for each of them, but I would really like to avoid this as there are quite a few items in the schema.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072357/extract-schema-for-sql-server-compact-edition) (possible duplicate I just found). I'd rather not use an external tool as suggested, since this is at work and I'd need to get approval to use one. Nor do I want one big `Create Database` script - I need separate scripts for each table/sproc/function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
   object_name(obj.object_id), 
   sch.name, 
   co.definition 
from 
   sys.objects obj 
   join sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = obj.schema_id
   left join sys.sql_modules co on co.object_id = obj.object_id
where 
   sch.name = 'DBO' --here goes your schema name
```

--The syscoments table was used back in sql 2000 and you should not use it anymore - but when so it is the sys.syscomments table

Comment: This works, thanks. Getting a strange behaviour though - it works for every schema _except_ the one I'm looking for. Could any configuration or anything stop the schema from showing up in this query/sys.objects? I've made sure that the objects are definitely in the right schema, so it's not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Premium includes database project tooling support that allows you to perform database schema comparisons between databases (where you can filter to only a specified database schema) and extract all the objects (and configuration) in a live database to a VS2010 database project, creating a script per object.

See [Working with Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Something based on

```
SELECT [text] FROM [syscomments]
```